# Connect to the internet via Virtualbox Guest VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

I have a Virtualbox guest Ubuntu VM and I need to connect my host to a VPN via a client that is installed on the guest VM only, so to let the host connect to the internet I want to pass through the guest so that the host will be connected to the VPN.

Is that possible? If yes, can you please show me the steps to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's probably possible, but it's not a simple task.

### Supposed problems

1. A VPN connection for client access usually provides the client with only one IP address, through which it is not possible to directly share access to other network nodes or entire networks on the client side.
2. In a host-virtual machine arrangement, VPN access can be easily shared when the VPN tunnel is terminated on the host. The VM connects to the host and thus to the VPN via a NAT connection. But in the reverse arrangement it is difficult.

### Interconnection design (not tested, no warranty)

1. Connect the VM to the network by using a bridge connection, not a NAT. The VM must obtain a separate IP address different from the host IP address.
2. Connect the host and VM mutually using another network interface of the isolated network type. The VM will have two interfaces, one outward, which will be used for the VPN, and the other only to connect the VM to the host.
3. Set up a masquerade in the VM so that the IP address of the host (**C**) in the isolated network is hidden, and so that the host can access the selected external address through the isolated network, through the VM using NAT. In this case, the bridged interface of the VM is used to go to the external address.
4. To test host access to the public address via VM and NAT, modify the routing on the **host**. Add a static route:
   `sudo ip route add <ext_IP_addr> via <isolated_net_VM_IP_addr>`
   where:
   `<ext_IP_addr>` is for instance Google web IP address 142.251.36.100 (or any other live web address)
   `<isolated_net_VM_IP_addr>` is real IP address of the VM in isolated network between host and VM. The **D** address in diagram.
5. The selected address of the external website (**E**) should be accessible from the host via the VM now. All other sites should be accessible directly from the host without the participation of the VM.
6. Add another route to the host. Its destination network is the address of the remote VPN network behind the tunnel. The gateway (via address) will again be the address **D**, see diagram.
   `sudo ip route add <ext_VPN_net> via <isolated_net_VM_IP_addr>`
7. Activate the VPN tunnel from the VM and test the availability of the target VPN first from the VM and then from the host. If routing doesn't work, check metrics of the routes in host. Newly added routes should have a better metric than other routes, otherwise they will not apply. Command to display routes: `ip route`

[image]

### Answer edit

- Any usual virtualization platform should allow to create at least 3 basic types of the guest network connection: NAT, bridge, isolated. Interface **D** is in isolated network, interface **B** is in bridged network.
- The Guest NAT/ masquerade must be set internally in the Guest operating system e.g. using `iptables`, not by selecting the host network connection type NAT.
- It is necessary to enable IP routing in the Guest. Any packet transfer via the Guest will not work without this feature enabled.

#### Guest IP routing check and enabling

##### The checking

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

##### The enabling

```
vi  /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Add the line:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

Reboot and re-check.

#### NAT/masquerade setting

Sorry, I did not tested described configuration, it is example only.

##### Example of used networks

- Let the **D** interface IP address be 10.2.2.1/24.
- Let the **B** interface IP address be 192.168.1.50/24.

There are several variants of address translation, depending on the circumstances you need to choose the right one.

##### Source NAT (SNAT)

It is valid in case the **B** address is fixed, manually set.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.2.2.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.50
```

##### Masquerade

It is valid in case the **B** address is dynamically assigned e.g. using DHCP.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.2.2.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

##### Final tasks

The configuration must be saved as persistent after it is verified that it works.
This also applies to static routes (steps #4 and #6 above) and turning on routing.
The method of saving depends on the type of used firewall management.

See the examples how to do it in older version of Linux (without UFW):

- https://sharadchhetri.com/save-iptables-permanently-on-ubuntu/
- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-save-iptables-firewall-rules-permanently-on-linux/

Newer Ubuntu with UFW firewall management:

- https://www.onworks.net/documentation/ubuntuserverguide/part253.php

The example also describes how to enable the routing using the UFW. Look the line containing `net/ipv4/ip_forward=1` and its comment.

Comment: Great explanation thank you very much! About 1. and 2. so having "Adapter 1: Bridged Adapter" and "Adapter 2: NAT" (for VPN) should be the way, right? And about 3. could you please be more specific on how to set up such a masquerade? Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Any usual virtualization platform should allow to create at least 3 basic types of the guest network connection: NAT, bridge, isolated. Interface D is in isolated network, interface B in bridged network. The NAT must be set internally in the Guest e.g. using iptables. I will edit my answer and add some details.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm not that expert to do that on my own :)

Comment: I extended the answer.